# typeof and a Base class

Tags: c#

Consider the following

```
    class Base
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    class Sub1 : Base
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
    }

    class Sub2 : Base
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
    }

    class Wrapper
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public Sub1 sub1 { get; set; }
        public Sub2 sub2 { get; set; }
    }
```

what i am trying to do is the following, i have this utility function to get sql type from clr type

```
  private static Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> types;
    public static SqlDbType GetSqlDbType(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        if (types == null)
        {
            types = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>();
            types.Add(typeof(Int32), SqlDbType.Int);
            types.Add(typeof(Int32?), SqlDbType.Int);
            types.Add(typeof(decimal), SqlDbType.Decimal);
            //etc
          //the problem is here i want to return SqlDbType.VarBinary for every class that inherits Base
            types.Add(typeof(Base), SqlDbType.VarBinary);
        }
        return types[type];
    }
```

from this function i want to return SqlDbType.VarBinary if the type is inherited from the Base class, is this possible?

Comment: Try IsAssignableFrom( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types in your dictionary seem to be all value types, that aren't impacted by inheritance. That would remain true even if you add a `string` to `SqlDbType.NVarChar` mapping. Because of that, you can simply do:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> types;

public static SqlDbType GetSqlDbType(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    if (types == null)
    {
        types = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>();
        types.Add(typeof(Int32), SqlDbType.Int);
        types.Add(typeof(Int32?), SqlDbType.Int);
        types.Add(typeof(decimal), SqlDbType.Decimal);
        // etc
    }

    SqlDbType result;

    if (types.TryGetValue(type, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return SqlDbType.VarBinary;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
    if (types.TryGetValue(type, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else if (typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        return SqlDbType.VarBinary;
    }
    else
    {
        // whatever, for example:
        throw new ArgumentException(type);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but it's going to be a little bit more complicated than your example. A quick example:

```
typeof(int?).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int))
```

The IsAssignableFrom method will allow you to check if there's an implicit cast between the two types - in the case of an inherited class, this is a given. So you can say

```
typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

However, as you can see, this means you can't use a Dictionary for the types anymore - you have to check every single possibility separately, and in the proper order. The easiest way would be to treat some types as simple (Dictionary lookup) and some as supporting inheritance (List of base types).